# FORMAT(SUM(Value*Value), 'C') does not allow me to order by DESC properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm currently trying to list OrderRevenue descending, but it lists the values descending improperly when I test my query.

What I've tried using:

```
SELECT o.OrderID, DATEPART(YEAR,o.OrderDate) AS OrderYear, DATEPART(QUARTER,o.OrderDate) AS OrderQuarter,
       E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS EmployeeName, C.CustomerName, S.ShipperName, SUM(d.Quantity) AS OrderItems, FORMAT(SUM(d.Quantity*p.Price), 'C') AS OrderRevenue
  FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN Employees e
      ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Customers c
      ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN Shippers s
      ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails d
      ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Products p
      ON  d.ProductID = p.ProductID
 GROUP BY o.OrderID, DATEPART(YEAR,o.OrderDate), DATEPART(QUARTER,o.OrderDate),
       E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName, C.CustomerName, S.ShipperName, P.Price
ORDER BY OrderRevenue DESC
```

What it prints out for me:

| OrderRevenue |
| --- |
| $997.50 |
| $997.50 |
| $986.50 |
| $98.00 |
| $977.20 |

As you can see it is not properly descending in value. Did I use the Format() method incorrectly?

**The SQL Schema I'm using is public, so feel free to test your query results on W3 if that would help you, help me better:**
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_datepart

Would really appreciate any explanation as to why SQL Server doesn't like my code. Thanks!

Comment: `FORMAT` returns a string so you get alphabetical ordering. Where `111` sorts before `9` in ascending order. You can `ORDER BY SUM(d.Quantity*p.Price) DESC` to get numeric ordering

Comment: ORDER BY `OrderRevenue` DESC where `OrderRevenue` datatype is string, so it will order by string format, when you need to do the sorting by number then make sure its datatype is always numeric.

Comment: @MartinSmith I appreciate the response. How/Where do I include the Format() to introduce the values as currency values? This would solve the ordering issue, however, I do need to have it display as $900.25, $34.93, etc in a descending order.

Comment: You just need to change your `ORDER BY`. You can leave the `SELECT` list alone.

Comment: Oh wow. Yeah that did the trick. I'll keep this in mind next time. Thanks @MartinSmith . If you'd like to, you can submit your answer and I'll pin it as most helpful. Cheers

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK Understood, I'll keep that in mind moving forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this `ORDER BY SUM(d.Quantity*p.Price) DESC` in order by

```
SELECT o.OrderID, DATEPART(YEAR,o.OrderDate) AS OrderYear, DATEPART(QUARTER,o.OrderDate) AS OrderQuarter,
       E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS EmployeeName, C.CustomerName, S.ShipperName, SUM(d.Quantity) AS OrderItems, FORMAT(SUM(d.Quantity*p.Price), 'C') AS OrderRevenue
  FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN Employees e
      ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Customers c
      ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN Shippers s
      ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails d
      ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Products p
      ON  d.ProductID = p.ProductID
 GROUP BY o.OrderID, DATEPART(YEAR,o.OrderDate), DATEPART(QUARTER,o.OrderDate),
       E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName, C.CustomerName, S.ShipperName, P.Price
ORDER BY SUM(d.Quantity*p.Price) DESC
```

Or you can do it like this also

```
select *,FORMAT(f1.OrderRevenue, 'C') as OrderRevenue from (SELECT o.OrderID, DATEPART(YEAR,o.OrderDate) AS OrderYear, DATEPART(QUARTER,o.OrderDate) AS OrderQuarter,
       E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName AS EmployeeName, C.CustomerName, S.ShipperName, SUM(d.Quantity) AS OrderItems, SUM(d.Quantity*p.Price) AS OrderRevenue
  FROM Orders o
    INNER JOIN Employees e
      ON o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN Customers c
      ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN Shippers s
      ON o.ShipperID = s.ShipperID
    INNER JOIN OrderDetails d
      ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Products p
      ON  d.ProductID = p.ProductID
 GROUP BY o.OrderID, DATEPART(YEAR,o.OrderDate), DATEPART(QUARTER,o.OrderDate),
       E.FirstName + ' ' + E.LastName, C.CustomerName, S.ShipperName, P.Price) f1
ORDER BY f1.OrderRevenue DESC
```

Comment: Kinda nice to mention that this is expanding on an existing comment by Martin